# MAUI Migration - Xamarin.Android.Common.targets error XA4215

Tags: xamarin.android, maui

I have an app I migrated from Xamarin.Android to .NET MAUI Android. I am getting some errors.

I have tried:

- Clean & Rebuild
- Deleting bin/obj folders
- Nuget package manager
- dotnet restore
- checked for "Xamarin" in the project
- Looked for [Register] in the solution, it doesn't appear to exist anywhere

**Questions**:

1. I don't understand why, as the app is MAUI so why would anything
   Xamarin show up? (Xamarin.Android.Common.Targets - what is this? I
   can't find it on google search). Its not even in the directory for
   the solution/project.
2. What do I need to do to resolve these errors?

**Problem**:

> Error XA4215 The Java type
> mono.android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat_OnActiveChangeListenerImplementor
> is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the
> [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted.
> AndroidAppCore C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.43\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets
>
> Error XA4215
> `mono.android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat_OnActiveChangeListenerImplementor`
> generated by:
> Android.Support.V4.Media.Session.MediaSessionCompat+IOnActiveChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null  AndroidAppCore  C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.43\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets
>
> Error XA4215
> `mono.android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat_OnActiveChangeListenerImplementor`
> generated by:
> Android.Support.V4.Media.Session.MediaSessionCompat+IOnActiveChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.Media, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null   AndroidAppCore  C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.43\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets 1513

Comment: Did your project refer to any other project or library that used the android.support package?

Comment: I unloaded one of the other projects (temporarily) and it got rid of these errors

Answer (score 0):

As an answer:

The Maui project uses **AndroidX** instead of the **Android.Support**. So Please make sure that you have migrate the **Android.Support package** to **AndroidX package** when you migrate xamarin project to maui project.

Note: **No only the Main project but also the other projects main project referenced.**

Comment: Does this mean I should download the Nuget packages for AndroidX? 
And also use the using statements for AndroidX in the c# files?

Comment: Yes, the android support package was duplicated. @angleUr

Comment: I added AndroidX, but VS is saying that AndroidX is deprecated. Here is an example:
            LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance(this).RegisterReceiver(patientLogoutReceiver, new IntentFilter("LogoutReceiver"));

When I hover over, it says: [deprecated] class AndroidX.LocalBroadcastManager.Content.LocalBroadcastManager

Comment: This is because the class is deprecated not the androidx. Please check : [LocalBroadcastManager is now deprecated, how to send data from service to activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74264850/localbroadcastmanager-is-now-deprecated-how-to-send-data-from-service-to-activi). @angleUr